# How to delete a file that has not been accessed recently?

Tags: command-line, files

How to find a file on Ubuntu that does not access for a recently ? I want to delete all files that have not been accessed for a long time . If I do it manually it will consume lots of time. Is there any command  for that ?

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/579211/how-to-delete-file-by-access-time-in-linux

Comment: This could be dangerous if the file is used by an application which then breaks. The application itself should be deleted with `sudo apt-get remove application`

Answer (score 7):

The 'find' command has an option called '-atime' for exactly this usage. If you want to find all files recursively under a directory, that have not been accessed for 30 days use:

```
find /directory/path/ -type f -atime +29
```

I think it is always using this first command to list which files you're operating on, before deleting. If you want to delete them use:

```
find /directory/path/ -type f -atime +29 -delete
```

As mentioned by [Amias](https://askubuntu.com/users/541244/amias) in comments, not all filesystems use atime. You can also search by modified time (modifications to the file contents) with `-mtime` or changed time (changes to file permissions/ownership etc) with `ctime`.

It is worth noting that `find`'s time structure is unusual in that it searches in 24 hr units for days, so what you may think is 3 days old, find may think is only 2 days old. Hence the use of +29 for 30 days. The `+` is used to specify, more than an number of days, `-` can be used to specify less than.

If you don't want the search to be recursive, you can limit how far it descends into the directory tree with `-maxdepth n` where n is the number of directories to step down through.

Comment: not all filesystems support atime or have it enabled  in their mount options. It can be a performance boost to disable it for some systems depending on their workloads

Comment: Cheers, incorporated that information into the answer.

Comment: By default, on Linux (on all filesystems i have checked), the `atime` is actually `relatime` (relative access time), this is a default mount option now, so be careful with any decision based on checking of the access time.

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like a job for `find`

Example:

```
find -atime +1
```

This will return all files in your current directory (recursively) that have been accessed more than 1 day ago

See `man find` for more information about possible arguments to find.